# MySQL aggregation with specific condition which depends on the row

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to add an extra condition to an accumulation which is depending on the specific row.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
select @datee := DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y-%m") datee, count(distinct name) new
from requests where name not in (select name from requests where DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y-%m") != @datee) 
group by datee;
```

In words: For every date it should show the number of names which only occur on that particular month.

Result could look like this:

```
datee   new
2018-11 343  <-- all these names only occur in 2018-11
2018-12 384  <-- all these names only occur in 2018-12
2019-01 438  ...
2019-02 460  ...
2019-03 442
2019-04 463
2019-05 470
2019-06 290
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simplified version of your data you could check that the name only occurs in one month and join with a count(distinct).

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(name varchar (1), mm int);

insert into t values
('a',1),('a',2),('a',3),
('b',2),
('c',1),('c',1),
('d',3),
('e',2),('e',2);



select mm,count(distinct t.name) obs
from t
join
(
select name, count(distinct mm) occurances
from
t 
group by name having occurances = 1 
) s on s.name = t.name
group by mm;

+------+-----+
| mm   | obs |
+------+-----+
|    1 |   1 |
|    2 |   2 |
|    3 |   1 |
+------+-----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note a disappears entirely since appears in all 3 months.